# Restart user systemd after groupadd

Tags: systemd, services, group

I let systemd manage a service `myservice` in a user's homedir. When I add that user to a new group, the running service does not pick up that group. Even when restarting with

```
systemctl --user restart myservice
```

the restarted service still doesn't have the access it should have through the new group.

I think this is because the `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` process is not restarted and keeps the old privileges. After a reboot, `myservice` has the privileges. So I know the problem lies somewhere along the process tree.

Adding groups will be a somewhat common operation and it's inconvenient to reboot. Can I restart the `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` process so it picks up the new privileges and passes them to `myservice`?